# How is reduce implemented?

Tags: swift

Looking to up my game in functional programming and to start I've chosen to do a deep dive into `reduce(into:_)` and how it works..

Here is a good example of how it works:

```
let letters = "abracadabra"
let letterCount = letters.reduce(into: [:]) { counts, letter in
counts[letter, default: 0] += 1
}
// letterCount == ["a": 5, "b": 2, "r": 2, "c": 1, "d": 1]
```

When I visit the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) of course the function body is not present for me to examine.. so my question is.. how might this function body be implemented.. if I can make my own version of `reduce(into:_)` I would feel content knowing I understand **truly** how it works.

Anyone have any ideas of how this function body may be implemented?

Comment: Swift is open-source, so you can inspect [the implementation of `reduce(_:_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L624) and [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L681) directly if you'd like

Comment: @ItaiFerber Interesting, is every function available? I know its open source but for the methods developed by the Swift team themselves, that wouldn't be available would it?

Comment: The whole of the Swift standard library and compiler are free for you to inspect (though the source for most Apple-specific frameworks is not provided). Poke around! :)

Comment: You can always think of reduce as a loop with an accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Here, for posterity, is [the standard library implementation of reduce](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d9b14893f0a8b02270fa92fa5c0c37d15574da03/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L624-L634) as of today, 2021-08-16 (though it has not changed in years).

```swift
public func reduce<Result>(
    _ initialResult: Result,
    _ nextPartialResult:
      (_ partialResult: Result, Element) throws -> Result
  ) rethrows -> Result {
    var accumulator = initialResult
    for element in self {
      accumulator = try nextPartialResult(accumulator, element)
    }
    return accumulator
  }
```